# how set a specific picture for window 7 logon screen

Tags: windows-7

[image]

in windows 7 when we use of classic logon method they will be a empty frame that there will be no picture inside that. the question is can i set a specific picture for show when logon screen appear? for example our company logo for all users.

Comment: This will give you some options... http://www.techspot.com/guides/224-change-logon-screen-windows7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ITsolution gave you right link, I just want to duplicate steps described in external [link](http://www.techspot.com/guides/224-change-logon-screen-windows7/) just in case if it would be unavailable, then one may still found this solution

1. Open the Windows Start menu and enter `regedit` into the search bar.
2. Right click on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and select Find.
3. Search for `OEMBackground`, which should be in
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Authentication/LogonUI/Background`.
   If the key does not exist, add a new `DWORD` value with the name
   `OEMBackground`.
4. Double click on the entry `OEMBackground`, and change the value from
   <kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>1</kbd>.
5. Open Windows Explorer and go to the following path:
   `%windir%/system32/oobe`.
6. Create a new folder named `info`, and open it.
7. Create a new folder within `info` named `backgrounds`.
8. Rename your desired wallpaper as `backgroundDefault.jpg` and place
   it inside the folder `backgrounds` (**images must be less than 245KB
   in size and has at least 640x480 resolution**).
9. log off or reboot or simply lock your screen with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to apply new settings.

For those who want to manage it via GPO and follow more detailed process (with screenshots) may want to see the article on [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/) web site.

Credits goto to @ITSolutions and article on www.techspot.com and [Chris Hoffman](http://www.howtogeek.com/author/chrishoffman/) @www.howtogeek.com

P.S.

> Note that selecting a new theme in the Appearance and Personalization
>   window will “unset” this registry value. Selecting a theme will change
>   the value of the key to the value stored in the theme’s .ini file,
>   which is probably 0 – if you change your theme, you’ll have to perform
>   this registry tweak again, but changing the setting in group policy will allow it to persist even when you change your theme, but the Group Policy Editor is only available in Professional editions of Windows.

Comment: 1. %windir%system32oobe i can not find that

Comment: I edited my answer, it should be `%windir%/system32/oobe`, probably original site stripped slashes

Comment: i have created the folders and placed a small picture on that but nothing happened.

Comment: please first test that yourself

Comment: @sajad Is your image is a JPG and less than 245kb ? Does image resolution match display's resolution?

Comment: it is 20kb - 300x400 - 300dpi - named to backgroundDefault.jpg

Comment: @sajad I always testing solutions before I going to post something on public resources, I did it, and it works perfectly. Just checked mine image, it is 219kb 795x545 with 24bits color. Try resolution at least 640 x 480

Comment: may you please add a visual guide?  i think its better. anyway i  rated your answer

Comment: @sajad I added in the answer another [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/) from howtogeek.com with detailed screenshots